# How to localize Featured Item Slider modul?

Tags: module, localization, translation, orchardcms, po

I'd like to translate Featured Item Slider module (http://gallery.orchardproject.net/List/Modules/Orchard.Module.FeaturedItemSlider) for Orchard.

I found its localization in http://crowdin.com/project/orchard-cms-gallery but after translation of all strings and downloading of PO file, I don't know where to put it. I tried to create Modules\Sunkist.FeaturedItemSlider\App_Data\Localization\cs-CZ\ folder and put PO file inside, but it didn't work (other than that I have whole Orchard in cs-CZ localization).

Does anybode have a clue, how to localize this module?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Where did you create it? That should have worked. Are the translations you checked really in the file?

Comment: I created translations on https://crowdin.com/project/orchard-cms-gallery/cs#/Gallery/Modules/FeaturedItemSlider and than downloaded PO file of that translation. It contains all translations (checked via POedit), but it doesnt work. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It should work. Did you enable the culture in settings? Do you have a module in place that switches the culture?

Comment: Hi Bertrand, Yes and Yes. I really don't know, what might be a problem here... I'll try to reinstall orchard, hopefully it will help. Thank you for your time and patience!